# Save state on configuration change is not working with two layouts in the form of inflated fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-orientation

I've an Activity with 4 tabs and each tab is a fragment (call it *tabFrags*) containing inflated fragments in it. Those *tabFrags* have different layouts in portrait and landscape modes.

I'm storing state in tabFragment like this

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putString(LAST_INPUT, etInput.getText().toString().trim());
}
```

When fragment restore I do the following thing

```
@Override
public void onViewStateRestored(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null && savedInstanceState.containsKey(LAST_INPUT)) {
        inputString = savedInstanceState.getString(LAST_INPUT);
        etInput.setText(inputString);
    }
}
```

When I print the value of **inputString** it shows value in it but doesn't set it to `EditText`.

Please guide me what i'm doing wrong here.

Comment: So, basically you claim, that `etInput.setText("someText");` won't change the contents of `etInput`?

Comment: yes, it remains empty but I can see in debugging that `inputString` has value in it.

Comment: That means, that you are in fact updating the `EditText` of the previous activity for some reason. Track down how many instances of activities/fragments you actually have. Try to switch from portrait to landscape say 20 times, if you suffer OutOfMemoryException, that means you are somehow keeping a reference to the previous activity.

Comment: It's not crashing but I can see in android monitor that allocated memory is being increased on every rotation. I checked my code, there is no previous activity reference. Can you guide me how can I confirm and remove previous references?

Comment: Use [`LeakCanary`](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to detect the memory leak.